# Is there any way to block certain sites, eg MacKeeper?

Tags: ipad, safari, url

MacKeeper (and other sites) adverts pop up on some video sites which I find very irritating. Is there any way to block specific URLs in Safari?

This occurs both on Mac and iPad. Ideally, I'd like a solution I can directly apply to the iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com).  You can apply it to your entire network using their name servers and block categories or specific URL's.  Although the ad might show up as a frame to a 'Website Blocked' page from OpenDNS, you'll probably find it useful (it's free).

Answer (score 1):

My prefered solution is using [glimmerblocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) which is actually an ad blocker but can be also used to just block specific web sites/URLs.

For iDevices it's a bit more difficult (at least if not jailbroken). Glimmerblocker supports a proxy mode though which allows you to point Mobile Safari to the Mac running Glimmerblocker. Of course this requires both systems to be online.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS the quickest way is to edit hosts file:

> sudo nano /etc/hosts

add the following line to the end of the file:

> 127.0.0.1       mackeeper.com